Analysis of Digit Distribution in Powers of a Uniformly Distributed Random Variable
This problem is from S.-T. Yau College Student Mathematics Contests 2024.
Question:
Let X have a uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]$ and let $N_{m,k}$ be the digit in the $m$-th place to the right of the decimal point in $X^k$.
(a) Find $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} P(N_{m,m}=i)$ for $i=0,1,2,...,9$.
(b) Let $k(m)$ be a function of $m$, taking values greater than 1. Find a necessary and sufficient condition on $k(m)$ such that $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} P(N_{m, k(m)} = i) = \frac{1}{10}$ for $i=0,1,2,...,9$.
My Attempts:
I'm very confused about (a) now, I have tried the following ways.
Attempt1:
To find the $k$-th digit of $x^k$, we multiply $x^k$ by $10^k$, then we define $Y = 10X$, then we have $Y \sim U[0, 10]$, and we only need to calculate $y^k - \{y^k\} ~ \text{mod} ~10$, where $\{y\}$ represents the fractional part of $y$. And we know $y^k \leq 10^k$.
For the digit $i$, we only need to satisify the following formula
\begin{equation}
10n+i \leq y^k < 10n+i+1, ~ n=0, \cdots, 10^{k-1}-1,
\end{equation}
and then we can have $y^k - \{y^k\} ~ \text{mod} ~10 = i ~ \text{mod} ~10$.
Solving the above inequality we can have $(10n+i)^{\frac{1}{k}} \leq y < (10n+i+1)^{\frac{1}{k}}$, so we can get the probability formula as
\begin{equation}
P(N_{k,k} = i) = \frac{1}{10} \sum_{n=0}^{10^{k-1}-1} [(10n+i+1)^{\frac{1}{k}} - (10n+i)^{\frac{1}{k}}].
\end{equation}
The last thing we need to do is to solve the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} P(N_{k,k} = i) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{10} \sum_{n=0}^{10^{k-1}-1} [(10n+i+1)^{\frac{1}{k}} - (10n+i)^{\frac{1}{k}}].
\end{equation}
However, I am unsure about how to proceed further with the limit.
Attempt2:
I write $x$ in the following way
$$x = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_j}{10^j},$$
and then try to analysis the pattern of the sequence, also failed, I think this way is more complicated then Attempt1.
How can I get the problem out, should I directly solve the limit or there are other beautiful ways to solve it? Thanks!

Let's get good enough (lower and upper) bounds for the sum, in closed form.
Put $f_k(x)=(x+1)^{1/k}-x^{1/k}$, so that (for $b$-ary system, in our case $\color{blue}{b=10}$)
$$
P(N_{m,k}=i)=b^{-m/k}\sum_{0\leqslant n<b^{m-1}}f_k(bn+i).
$$
Now use the fact that $f_k$ is monotonically non-increasing. Then we get a lower bound
$$
f_k(bn+i)\geqslant\frac1b\sum_{j=0}^{b-1}f_k(bn+i+j)=\frac1b\Big(\big(b(n+1)+i\big)^{1/k}-(bn+i)^{1/k}\Big)
$$
(which is easy to sum over $n$) and similarly, for $n>0$, an upper bound
$$
f_k(bn+i)\leqslant\frac1b\sum_{j=0}^{b-1}f_k(bn+i-j)=\frac1b\Big((bn+i+1)^{1/k}-\big(b(n-1)+i+1\big)^{1/k}\Big).
$$
Summing these bounds over $0<n<b^{m-1}$, we get the following estimates:
\begin{align*}
P(N_{m,k}=i)&\geqslant b^{-m/k}f_k(i)+b^{-1-m/k}\big((b^m+i)^{1/k}-(b+i)^{1/k}\big);
\\
P(N_{m,k}=i)&\leqslant b^{-m/k}f_k(i)+b^{-1-m/k}\big((b^m-b+i+1)^{1/k}-(i+1)^{1/k}\big).
\end{align*}

If we put $k=m$ and take $m\to\infty$, we get the answer for (a):
$$
\color{blue}{
\lim_{m\to\infty}P(N_{m,m}=i)=\begin{cases}
(2b-1)/b^2, & \hfill i=0 \\ \hfill (b-1)/b^2, & 0<i<b
\end{cases}}
$$
Likewise, for (b) the condition is $\color{blue}{\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}k(m)/m=0}$.
Indeed, if it holds, then $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}P(N_{m,k(m)}=i)=1/b$ (for each $i$) follows easily from the estimates above. Otherwise, there is an increasing sequence $(m_j)$ such that $\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}m_j/k(m_j)$ is finite; then (already) the limit $\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}P(N_{m_j,k(m_j)}=i)$ is again different for $i=0$ and $0<i<b$.
